# Conditional labeling in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, labeling

Is it possible to create labels based on the value of certain fields in my data?

For example, I only want to label a column 'name' when 'age' was a certain value etc or a certain field was a given length.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for post, managed to figure it out myself in the end;

```
def FindLabel ( [a] , [b], [c]  ):
  if [a] == "value":
    return [b] 
  else:
    return [c]
```